# SSH key not recognized after installation (also: can I store keys on NTFS)

Tags: linux, ssh, ntfs, fedora, ssh-keys

I've reinstalled my Fedora 15. I decided to keep my SSH keys, including Github key, so I won't have to generate new one.
However, when I copied them back from NTFS partition to `~/.ssh` directory, Github seems to not to recognize it's key:

```
[maciej@PC05 .ssh]$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Then SSH quits.

Github key is named `id_rsa` (I have few SSH keys used for connecting with different hosts; secondary question: is it a good practice?). I've added it (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`; I had to fix permissions first), however it hasn't fixed the problem.

I've also had problems with generating SSH key to connect with my laptop using Seahorse, however I was able to deal with it by using CLI instead and I don't think this issue is linked to my problem.

So, should I generate new SSH key, or can I fix this one somehow?

I'm also going to reinstall Fedora on my laptop - can I just move whole `.ssh` directory to NTFS partition and link `~/.ssh` to it to (my NTFS setup allows me to use privileges, so that's not a problem)? Will it let me avoid this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162676/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-ssh-private-public-key-pair-on-2-machines-to-acces ... you should not necessarily need to recreate keys.

Comment: That actually helped. It was about permissions stuff, it seems like I haven't fully fixed them. Would you please post it as a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162676/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-ssh-private-public-key-pair-on-2-machines-to-acces. I ran into the same issue, and it was because of